# Exception policy for __get_item__

Tags: python

If I implement `__get_item__()` for my custom container of objects should it throw `KeyError` in case of missing element or it is allowed for the method to return some default value, e.g., `None`.

Comment: Presuming you mean `__getitem__`,  it depends what you're using it for.

Comment: @khelwood Ok. I thought Python enforces some mandatory behaviour on __get_item__.

Comment: The only thing I'm aware of is that if you use the default iteration behaviour for classes with `__getitem__` then it should raise an `IndexError` when you get past the end of the sequence. But that very much depends on what you're using your class for.

Comment: See [`datamodel#__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)